# how can i prove that a vertex intersect the circumference (...)?

Tags: trigonometry

Given:
A circle of unknown dimensions, 2 squares of a known size (x).
The squares intersect at shared vertex F, at 90º.
The squares intersect the circle at vertices A, B, and D

I'm trying to prove that vertex C is also on the circumference.

I know that A+B + circle center creates an Isosceles triangle. And  that the distance of A, B & D is equal (they're all granted to be R length from the center).

I can show that angle AD⦠CD is 45º.
I can show that CD also equals x, and that the Isosceles triangles  between the circle center and the square sizes overlap in shape and size.

but is that enough to declare: "Point C is on the circumference" ?

[image]

Comment: (IDK why the drawing is not displayed inside the question).   Oh great, SO punishes the readers ("You need at least 10 reputation to post images")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may verify that there is a point in the plane of equal distance from $A, B, C$, and $D$, namely the intersection of the bisector of $AB$ and the bisector of $CD$, so with this point as the center, one may draw a circle that passes through all four points $A, B, C$, and $D$. But given three points on the plane, there’s at most one circle passing through them all. So since your circle passes through $A, B$, and $D$, it must coincide with the circle above. Hence, it must pass through $C$ as well.

---

A slightly more direct argument: since the center of your circle is of same distance from $A, B$, and $D$, it must lie on the bisector of $AB$ and the bisector of $AD$. The latter bisector passes through $F$ and is of $45^\circ$ from the sides of the squares. As such, this intersection point is exactly the center of another square of side length $x$, to the bottom-left of the existing two squares. It is then clear that this intersection point lies on the bisector of $CD$ as well, so its distances from $C$ and $D$ equal. Thus, $C$ is on the circle.

(I don’t have the means to draw a diagram right now - if this is clear enough for OP, great. Otherwise I’ll draw a diagram to clarify the proof tomorrow.)